# MVC2 site widgets

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, widget

So I want a widget to stay with the user no matter where they are going off to the side. It will be there so they can copy and paste between web pages in my site. I don't want to use frames unless I have too. Any websites or examples would help a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A frame, iframe, popup, or writing a browser plugin are your options.

I wouldn't necessarily shun frames in this instance as this is an actual valid use for them.